# Public REST api: add protection level

Tags: django, api, rest, http-headers, django-rest-framework

I'm have a question. I have to implement some REST API for mobile App.
I using DJANGO Rest Framework.

For this API is not required some authentication system: all API are public, and the app can calls this API.

I would add a minimum level of protection.
My goal is to not allow any client to call These APIs.

I thought to implement on the server and on the mobile apps a function that takes as paramter (for example) the date + other info.

```
es: build_toke(date, secret_number) -> Md5 string
```

When the client invokes one of my API, it will put this string in the http request header.
The server will check this string running the same function and checking the result.

```
Md5_server = build_toke(date, secret_number) 
Md5_mobile = header_http.get_code()

if Md5_server == Md5_mobile -> OK
else return 401 (not authorized)
```

It might be a good idea?
You know something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **implement a `CheckMd5Header` [custom permission class](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions)**  which will compare the values of `Md5_server` and `Md5_mobile` and will allow access only if the 2 values are same.

To implement a custom permission, you will have to override the `BasePermission` class and implement `.has_permission()` method. This method should return `True` if the request should be granted access, and `False` otherwise.

```
class CheckMd5Header(permissions.BasePermission):
    """
    Permission class to check if the Md5 string in the 
    request header is same as of the Md5 server string
    """

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        md5_mobile = request.META.get('Md5_mobile') # get the value of md5 mobile header
        md5_server = build_toke(date, secret_number) # generate md5 server string
        return md5_server == md5_mobile # return True or False
```

Then, you need to add this permission class in your DRF settings.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        ...
        'my_app.permissions.CheckMd5Header', # specify custom permission class
    )
}
```

This tells DRF to use this permission class on any requests which occur. Only those requests for which the md5 value in headers matches with the md5 value of the server are allowed access.